# How can I correct my error in Python about IndentationError which cause my program not working properly?

Tags: python, algorithm

When I write my code, I get an error near of print like `"IndentationError: expected an indented block"`. Could you help me? This is my code example:

```
print("Enter your number: ")
num=int(input())
if(num%2):
print("ODD")
else:
print("Even")
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to read the documentation e.g. https://www.askpython.com/python/python-indentation

> When writing python code, we have to define a group of statements for functions and loops. This is done by properly indenting the statements for that block.

and

> It is preferred to use whitespaces for indentation than the tab character.

So add 4 spaces after if and else, so your code would look like

```
print("Enter your number: ")
num=int(input())
if(num%2):
    print("ODD")
else:
    print("Even")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your indentations
After an if or else statement you should put a tab like so:

```
print("Enter your number: ")
num=int(input())
if(num%2):
   print("ODD")
else:
   print("Even")
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation plays an important role in python, takecare of indentation when writing python code your one extra space or one less space can make your programe work faulty or doesn't work at all.

Working Code:

```
print("Enter your number: ")
num=int(input())
if(num%2):
    print("ODD")
else:
    print("Even")
```

When u in any loop, remember to press 4 single spaces or one tab and write code after that

Answer (score 0):

You need an indent of 4 spaces in the line after a ':'

```
if(num%2):
    print('ODD')
else:
    print('Even')
```

That's the working code.